# Access denied in SD card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdcard, sd-card

How to reproduce:
add a tag to the resource on the SD card

It looks like this bug does not affect Android 11

Log:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: space.taran.arknavigator, PID: 8596
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/1B0C-2304/DCIM/.ark-tags
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3351)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$writeStorage$2.invokeSuspend(PlainTagsStorage.kt:174)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$writeStorage$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$writeStorage$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:161)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage.writeStorage(PlainTagsStorage.kt:165)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage.access$writeStorage(PlainTagsStorage.kt:22)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$persist$2.invokeSuspend(PlainTagsStorage.kt:136)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$persist$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$persist$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:161)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage.persist(PlainTagsStorage.kt:90)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage.access$persist(PlainTagsStorage.kt:22)
at space.taran.arknavigator.mvp.model.repo.PlainTagsStorage$setTags$2.invokeSuspend(PlainTagsStorage.kt:68)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

```
    android:name="space.taran.arknavigator.ui.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest ....>   

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application ....>
```

on Activity

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```